# How does a g++ compiler realize multiple inheritance with virtual functions?

Tags: c++

It is mentioned in the book "Inside The C++ Object Model" that the derived class has `n - 1` extra virtual tables, that `n` is the number of the base classes. I did some experiments with g++ compiler and my machine is 64 bit.
Following is my code.

```
class A{
    private:
        int a;
    public:
        virtual void print() const{
            cout << a << endl;
        }

};

class B : A{
    private:
        int b;
    public:
        virtual  void set(int num){
            b = num;
        }
};


class C : public A, public B{
    private:
        int c;
    public:
        void print() const{
            cout << c << endl;
        }
        void set(int num){
            c = num;
        }
};
```

And I check the memory layout of each class in gdb:

```
(gdb) p a
$1 = (A) {
  _vptr.A = 0x400bb0 <vtable for A+16>, 
  a = 0
}
(gdb) p b
$2 = (B) {
  _vptr.B = 0x400b90 <vtable for B+16>, 
  b = 4196384
}
(gdb) p c
$3 = (C) {
  <A> = {
    _vptr.A = 0x400b50 <vtable for C+16>, 
    a = 4197101
  }, 
  <B> = {
    _vptr.B = 0x400b70 <vtable for C+48>, 
    b = 0
  }, 
  members of C: 
  c = 0
}
```

It shows that there are two `vptrs` in class C. Then I compile it gain with `-fdump-class-hierarchy`,and I get some information.

```
 Vtable for A
    A::_ZTV1A: 3u entries
    0     (int (*)(...))0
    8     (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI1A)
    16    (int (*)(...))A::print

    Class A
       size=16 align=8
       base size=12 base align=8
    A (0x0x7fe4654956c0) 0
        vptr=((& A::_ZTV1A) + 16u)

    Vtable for B
    B::_ZTV1B: 3u entries
    0     (int (*)(...))0
    8     (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI1B)
    16    (int (*)(...))B::set

    Class B
       size=16 align=8
       base size=12 base align=8
    B (0x0x7fe465495720) 0
        vptr=((& B::_ZTV1B) + 16u)

    Vtable for C
    C::_ZTV1C: 7u entries
    0     (int (*)(...))0
    8     (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI1C)
    16    (int (*)(...))C::print
    24    (int (*)(...))C::set
    32    (int (*)(...))-16
    40    (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI1C)
    48    (int (*)(...))C::_ZThn16_N1C3setEi

    Class C
       size=32 align=8
       base size=32 base align=8
    C (0x0x7fe46516e690) 0
        vptr=((& C::_ZTV1C) + 16u)
      A (0x0x7fe465495780) 0
          primary-for C (0x0x7fe46516e690)
      B (0x0x7fe4654957e0) 16
          vptr=((& C::_ZTV1C) + 48u)
```

Then I am confused with following questions.

1. `Class A
   size=16 align=8
   base size=12 base align=8`

   I don't understand why the size of class A is 16 and what do the base size and align mean? I thought the size of class A should be 12 bytes case the 8 bytes for `vptr` and 4 bytes for `int a`. The same for class B.
2. I thought there are 2 `vtables` of class C. But the result showed only one with 7 entries. what's the relationship between this `vtable` and the two `vptr` of class C?
3. The last row of showed that `vptr=((& C::_ZTV1C) + 48u)`, what does 48 mean? and of the last entry of  `vtable` of class C showed that 
   `48    (int (*)(...))C::_ZThn16_N1C3setEi` 
   what does it mean? it is not the name of virtual functions and the offset to top. why do the second `vptr` point to this entry?

Comment: regarding question 1, you need to take a look at struct padding. Your PC arch is 16-byte aligned. int takes 4 bytes, and the function pointer to print takes 8 bytes, thus 12 bytes for base size, and the last 4 bytes are for data alignment purposes. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)

Answer (score 0):

It is related to [vtables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table). With multiple inheritance, an object may have *several* of them (perhaps one for each super class containing virtual member functions).

Casting an object pointer to some of it parent classes may need adding some offset (to get the right vtable & member functions).